# How to interact with ZK time attendance machine database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, codeigniter, api

I am trying another approach in accessing the database of a ZK time Attendance machine. I am trying to make a cron in the server to access it mdb file in the Program Files. The cron will select all the data in the mdb file and transfer it in a Mysql database. I have no error in connecting to the database. But when I select data from checkinout table it returns nothing. can any body help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Please include your attempts in your question :)

Comment: I am looking for the answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the approach you were trying but probably more stable as it uses the SOAP and UDP interface the developers of the hardware designed: https://github.com/cobisja/tad-php